# Backgammon app for Android that allows playing with remote friend

Tags: android, game

I'm looking for a backgammon app which would let me invite a friend with the same (or compatible?) app on their device to play backgammon with me. The friend would have to be in my phone's contacts, or otherwise identifiable by phone number (not Facebook or other social media "friends").

I am not interested in apps which force me to use "coins" or are otherwise too contrived or glitzy. Just wanna play backgammon with a friend when they are far away.

Obviously, I would prefer something free, but so far the free apps I've seen which allow remote play are over the top with advertising or have gold flying everywhere. (The worst offender I've seen so far is [Backgammon Online - Lord of the Board](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.beachbumgammon&hl=en_US). I didn't even figure out how to play one game without having it match me up with some random stranger. Uninstalled immediately.) I would be willing to pay a smallish amount for reasonable quality, unintrusive software. I don't know exactly what a fair price is, because I am new to the world of smartphones, but it seems like 2 or 3 USD is common, and that sounds OK to me if the software is actually good. I might be willing to go even a little higher for something really well made.

As a point of reference, I am currently using [Backgammon Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.aifactory.backgammonfree&hl=en_US) for solo play, and find that it is decent. Something like that, but allowing me to play remotely with someone of my choosing, is what I'm looking for.

My question is very similar to [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/68890/free-backgammon-game-that-allows-playing-with-a-friend-on-different-computer) which asks for software which works on PC or Linux.